# Azure - How can I check if my first full backup is available

Tags: backup, restore, azure-sql-database

As per Microsoft documentation [Learn about automatic SQL Database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups)

**How often do backups happen?**

> Full database backups happen weekly, differential database backups
>   generally happen every few hours, and transaction log backups
>   generally happen every 5 - 10 minutes. The first full backup is
>   scheduled immediately after a database is created. It usually
>   completes within 30 minutes, but it can take longer when the database
>   is of a significant size. For example, the initial backup can take
>   longer on a restored database or a database copy. After the first full
>   backup, all further backups are scheduled automatically and managed
>   silently in the background. The exact timing of all database backups
>   is determined by the SQL Database service as it balances the overall
>   system workload.

Is there a way for me to check if my first full backup is completed and ready for restore?

I understand it will be first available in the same location and later replicated to other locations.  I also know that I can check by trying to add a new database from backup and see if my database backup shows up in the list.  I am more interested if there are system tables, management views that I can query to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseGeoBackup Powershell cmdlet to get all available backups on a specified server.

```
Get-AzureRMSqlDatabaseGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "ContosoResourceGroup" -ServerName "ContosoServer"
```

Hope this helps.